# ¿ Como saber el estado de un UIButton desde otra vista?

Tags: ios, swift

Tengo una vista donde va cambiando el estado de un UIButton de true a false varias veces en varias partes de código.
En otra vista tengo que implementar un método que según el estado del UIButton de esta otra vista haga una cosa u otra.
¿ Es posible usar algo parecido a "didset" para que según el estado de este UIButton llame a una función ? ¿ Tendría que usarlo con un protocolo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con la propiedad observable "didset" puedes como su nombre lo indica monitorear el cambio de valor de una propiedad en especifico, incluso si el nuevo valor es el mismo que el valor actual de la propiedad. 
Por ejemplo:

```
class MyButton : UIButton {

    override var isSelected: Bool {
       didSet {
        print("Cambio de \(oldValue) a \(isSelected)")
       }
    }
}

let button = MyButton()
button.isSelected = true //se visualizaría en consola la impresión del mensaje
```

Sin embargo con esto no estarías comunicando un controlador con otro para ello pueden existir diferentes formas. Una de ella como mencionas es hacer uso de un protocolo.

*No entendí muy bien como tienes la comunicación de tus controladores pero te pongo un ejemplo algo simple.

```
protocol CambioDelegate {
   func cambioEstadoBoton(boton:UIButton)
}

class ButtonController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: ViewController?
    @IBOutlet weak var boton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func clicEnBoton(_ sender: Any) {
       if boton.isSelected == true {
          boton.isSelected = false
       } else {
          boton.isSelected = true
          delegate?.cambioEstadoBoton(boton: boton)
       }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, CambioDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func cambioEstadoBoton(boton: UIButton) {
       print("Entra a cambio de estado")
    }
}
```

Donde la referencia de delegate podría darse por ejemplo si hay un segue en tu storyboard que es ejecutado para mostrar "ButtonController"

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 
{
   if segue.identifier == "ButtonController" {
       let vc = segue.destination as! ButtonController
       vc.delegate = self
   }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta supongo que ¿ Para monitorear la variable en varios controladores sin usar protocolo,  esta debe ser declarada como estatica ?

Comment: No se si te refieras a algo así                                                                  class Global {
    static let sharedInstance = Global()
    var estadoBoton: Bool = false
}                                                                                                                           y si podrías cambiar/obtener su valor  en cualquier controlador

Comment: Gracias de nuevo por tu respuesta